# Session destroy no funciona

Tags: php

En Index_prueba.php:

```
<?php
include('./auth_prueba.php');
$centro=$_SESSION['tienda'];
?>
<a href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesión</a>
```

En auth_prueba.php:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['tienda'])) {
//aqui se crean variables que luego se usarian en los demas phps
}
```

En logout.php  (Que es al que hace referencia el href de index)

```
$_SESSION = array();
$_COOKIE['Cookie'] = NULL;
$_SESSION['tienda'] = NULL;
unset($_COOKIE);
unset($_tienda);
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header("Location: http://index_prueba.php");
```

Pero no hay manera de que se destruya la sesión, en cuanto le clicas a "Cerrar sesión" se refresca la pagina pero no te pide que autentifiques como cuando entras.

Si necesitais mas informacion decidme.

Comment: ¿Qué tienes en `index_prueba.php`? ¿Qué pasa si después de cerrar sesión presionas la tecla `F5` para actualizar la página?

Comment: Prueba a ponerlo en este orden: `session_start(); session_destroy();`, pues la segunda no funciona sin la primera. Si no funciona, prueba de este modo: `$_SESSION = [];` Para más detalles, consulta [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472123/why-is-php-session-destroy-not-working). ¿Cuál es tu versión de PHP? Pregunto porque `session_unset();` es para versiones prehistóricas de PHP, si tu código no está orientado a la prehistoria deberías evitar su uso.